# How to get required roles for the current web service call in Spring Security Filter

Tags: java, spring, authentication, spring-security, servlet-filters

I have a Spring Security Filter, I want to get the required privileges for the current web service call. Is it possible or not because I searched on Google but didn't find any useful answer.

Answer (score -1):

```
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getAuthorities();
```